# jQuery mobile : search input in same line as header title

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image]

Is there anyway to make the search input align with the title? I realize only button can be at the same line with title.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a div around your input with the "data-role=fieldcontain" attribute.